# is this some types of method variable?

Tags: java, swing, oop, jakarta-ee, syntax

I was doing some swing java and ran into this (im still new to programming).

```
int maxXvalue = getSize().width;
```

basically is this a variable defined within a method called getSize() ?

I know for class variables its:   `className.variableName`

I know for objects variables its: `object.variableName`

so for methods is it?:            `method().variableName`

also in java how do i access inner class variables?
For example, a class named "Class" containing a subclass called "InnerClass":

would it be: `Class.InnerClass.variable`

or would it be just be: `InnerClass.variable`
without the container class referenced

Thanks for clearing up the confusion and misconceptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getSize()` is just returning an instance of a `Dimension` Object

```
width is just a field within that object.
```

Dimension JavaDocs here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Dimension.html

Comment: gotcha, so are there such things as method variables? what would be the syntax for accessing them

Comment: @adamkim you can access them just the way you are accessing them now. They are fields that have their access fields avaible for you to access directly instead of using a "getter" or something like `getHeight()`

Comment: if i have a method like this:
public void method(){
int z =1;
String a ="a"; // maybe i need a final modifier or somthing
}
how would i access those?

Comment: You can't access variables outside of their scope. If a variable is declared inside a method, they are restricted from access unless it's from inside that method.

Comment: gotcha so method().somthing means the variable within the returned object.  what about my question regarding the subclassed variables (or subclassed methods)?

Comment: @adamkim That method().something would only be true if a) method() is some method that returns an instance of some object, and b) if you have access to that field from wherever you're trying to access it from.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you tell me how to access subclassed (Innerclass) variables?  is it Class1.Class2.variable?